# Manage multiple state array searches and keep the original state array?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to build a search function to be able to search an Array in state.

```
 var searchString = "search word"
 var updatedList = cases.filter((item) => {
     return Object.keys(item).some(
         key => (item as any)[key]
             .toString()
             .toLowerCase()
             .search(searchString.toLowerCase()) !== -1
     );
 });

 this.setState({
     cases: updatedList
 })
```

This updates state.cases and renders the items found in the Array with objects, which is good. But when I'm doing another search, state.cases is of course updated and contains only the items from the search before.

How can I keep the "old" state before the first search and make multiple searches?

The cases in state is used in a component that renders a table with the result.

Comment: Are you using `typescript`?

Comment: yes i'm using typescript

Comment: Know this is a broad scoped solution but have you considered implementing redux?

Comment: You should filter your items inside the render function

Comment: you don't have to set another array in the state

Comment: have you tried sending `prevstate` as argument to `setState`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe don't set the state for the filtered cases ..? Just set the state for the search string and try this

```
render() {
    const { searchString } = this.state;
    const { cases } = this.props;
    let filteredCases = cases;
    if(!!searchString) {
        filteredCases = cases.filter((item) => {
            return Object.keys(item).some(
                key => (item as any)[key]
                    .toString()
                    .toLowerCase()
                    .search(searchString.toLowerCase()) !== -1
            );
        });
    }

    return <>{filteredCases}</>
}
```

So you will just filter out the cases based on your search string.

Comment: The cases state is used in react-table, so I want to update the state to render the search results.

Comment: So now you can just pass the `filteredCases` to the table to show the search results matching the string.

Comment: I still don't get how this could work. In ReactTable there's a data property. Here I specify this.state.cases. Then I click a "Search" button, I want it to re-render the state.cases. How can I use this return in both ReactTable and for my search button?

Comment: Like this maybe `<ReactTable data={filteredCases} {...otherProps}>`, `<SearchButton value={this.state.searchString} onChange={this.updateSearchString}/>`. Can you please create a fiddle or some sort with your code. It will be easier